# Dismiss view controller with custom animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am using this line of code to dismiss my view controller `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`, but I do not like the current animation. Instead I want to slide from left to right. Below is my attempt to test out an animation, but does not work.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {

        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 10
        transition.type = kCATransitionPush
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft

        self.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I believe what is happening here is that the the view controller is being dismissed at the same time that the animation begins. You could try  moving the self.dismiss(...) to the animations completion block and see if that works. If it doesn't, you can find lots of tutorials online on how to custom segues. I've never done it so I can't give you any pointers myself, but Ray Wenderlich is always a good place to go for in depth tutorials.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
transition.type = CATransitionType.reveal
transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```