# How to dismiss presentation controller with a custom animation

Tags: swift, swift3, uistoryboardsegue

I'm using Custom Segue class to navigate between controllers.

```
class CustomSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let firstVCView = self.source.view as UIView!
        let secondVCView = self.destination.view as UIView!

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        secondVCView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: screenHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(secondVCView!, aboveSubview: firstVCView!)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
            firstVCView?.frame = (firstVCView?.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -screenHeight))!
            secondVCView?.frame = (secondVCView?.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -screenHeight))!

        }) { (Finished) -> Void in
            self.source.present(self.destination as UIViewController,
                                                            animated: false,
                                                completion: nil)
        }
    } 
}
```

my question is how to dismiss with the opposite animation, 
in dismiss method, I don't have the source/destination view to take the width and height.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably found out already, but for other people landing on this topic, the solution is given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799143/dismiss-view-controller-with-custom-animation), namely doing the animation in the ViewController and then dismiss without animation.

Swift 4 code:

```
@IBAction func BackAction(_ sender: Any) {  
    let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    transition.type = CATransitionType.reveal
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft
    self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)

    self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```