# Dismiss ViewController using segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom segue I'm using "slide" a new view controller into view:

```
class SegueFromRight: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let src = self.source
        let dst = self.destination

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)},
            completion: { finished in
                src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And I've set up the segue in my Storyboard.

Now, when I'm done, I want to dismiss this view controller and go back to the preview controller. I am doing so like this:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, this uses the default "slide down" animation when it closes. I want to slide the view controller back out to the right (the opposite of my custom segue above). Is there a way I am dismiss a view controller using a custom segue? Or another way to achieve this?

Comment: You may like to use unwind segue.

Comment: It was the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799143/dismiss-view-controller-with-custom-animation maybe it can help you